# Custom mail routing rule in Exchange 2003

Tags: routing, exchange-2003

Given the scenario:

Microsoft Exchange Server 2003.

On the server, there is a recipient's mailbox, let's call it mj@myserver.com

Suppose I want all mail, that are received from restricted@sender.com not to be delivered to mj@myserver.com, but to be routed to mj@forrestricted.com

Is there a way to configure such routing on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Exchange Server 2003, the only way that you can accomplish this is to log onto the mailbox with Outlook and set up some rules; and some of those rules might be client side only (meaning you would need to leave Outlook running for them to continue to be processed).

With newer versions of Exchnage server, there are more options available to you; so you might consider an upgrade if this is important and an upgrade is possible.